# How to configure a geth full node for indexing token transactions?

Tags: go-ethereum, tokens, nodes, explorers, full-node

I am planning on sniping up an ethereum geth full node for querying purposes planning on using https://github.com/ethereumproject/explorer block explorer repo.

1. For bitcoin I used `-txindex=1` to enable indexing. What should I use here for geth?
2. I want to look up information about Ethereum tokens (ERC20, ether classic). What configurations do I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geth doesn't have an equivalent to txindex=1, and you do not need one because you can already query arbitrary transactions.

Unfortunately geth doesn't provide extra tools to easily query tokens, or other smart contracts. You have to use some other tool on top of it to interpret "internal transactions".

Answer (score 1):

Geth only supports indexing transactions hash, which can be enabled with `--txlookuplimit=0` arg. This will index all transactions' hash.

For smart contract analysis (i.e. token events) you'd have to index yourself or use a 3rd party service API to query.